# What is the difference between FilterRegistrationBean and DelegatingFilterProxy?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

Are both different ways to register a filter, FilterRegistrationBean provides ordering option. DelegatingFilterProxy is used as proxy to register filters, but how FilterRegistrationBean registers a filter?
What is the difference between both registering filters in servlet containers.

Spring boot uses FilterRegistrationBean but not DelegatingFilterProxy why?

Does FilterRegistrationBean adds filter directly as a servlet filter or it also uses the implementation like DelegatingFilterProxy?

Answer (score 1):

The [`DelegatingFilterProxy`] is used to configure a `Filter` in your application context, and do the URL mapping in a `web.xml` or replacement. It will do a lookup of the filter  in the `ApplicationContext` and execute the configured `Filter`. This class is also part of the Spring Framework. It is also a servlet `Filter` itself as it acts as a proxy for an actual `Filter` instance configured in the `ApplicationContext`.

The [`FilterRegistrationBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html) is, as the name implies, a bean used to provide configuration to register `Filter` instances. It can be used to provide things like URL mappings etc. It is an additional configuration component used by Spring Boot so that it can add the `Filter` referenced by this `FilterRegistrationBean` can be registered (or not!) as part of the filter chain.

Comment: Does FilterRegistrationBean adds filter directly as a servlet filter or it also uses the implementation like DelegatingFilterProxy?

Comment: `FilterRegistrationBean` is a configuration component only it isn't a filter itself. Its usecase is different, as I tried to explain, then the `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

Answer (score 0):

`FilterRegistrationBean` is a Spring Bean that helps you to register filters.

`DelegatingFilterProxy` is a filter itself. It can be registered into the ServletContext by using `FilterRegistrationBean` for example, like below:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterChainRegistration() {
DelegatingFilterProxy filterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
filterProxy.setTargetBeanName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(delegatingFilterProxy);
registrationBean.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
 registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
return registrationBean;
}
```

**EDIT:**

From [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html): "A ServletContextInitializer to register Filters in a Servlet 3.0+ container. Similar to the registration features provided by ServletContext but with a Spring Bean friendly design.
The Filter must be specified before calling RegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletContext). Registrations can be associated with URL patterns and/or servlets (either by name or via a ServletRegistrationBeans. When no URL pattern or servlets are specified the filter will be associated to '/*'. The filter name will be deduced if not specified.".

Comment: Does FilterRegistrationBean adds filter directly as a servlet filter or it also uses the implementation like DelegatingFilterProxy?

Comment: We can directly add filter with out FilterRegistrationBean using DelegatingFilterProxy. as DelegatingFilterProxy is registered as proxy filter in web.xml and request coming will be calling the actual implementation.

Comment: I've answered you into the post.

Comment: @Bean
    private Filter CORSFilter() {        return new CORSFilter();    }
we can simple add like this in spring boot annotation main class  but this config applies to context url i.e all requests.